# X and Y or Z - ternary operator

Tags: python, syntax, ternary-operator

In Java or C we have `<condition> ? X : Y`, which translates into Python as `X if <condition> else Y`.

But there's also this little trick: `<condition> and X or Y`.

While I understand that it's equivalent to the aforementioned ternary operators, I find it difficult to grasp how `and` and `or` operators are able to produce correct result. What's the logic behind this?

Comment: Related useful information, the expression `<condition> and X` will resolve to `X` (or `False`, if `<condition>` is `False`). Similar to how the `or` operator works. So it's a combination of two operators, not a special syntax.

Comment: The explanation is in here, once you break down the steps of the process: [Python's Logical Operator AND](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195322/pythons-logical-operator-and)

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36551857/4014959) helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> While I understand that it's equivalent to the aforementioned ternary
>   operators

This is incorrect:

```
In [32]: True and 0 or 1
Out[32]: 1

In [33]: True and 2 or 1
Out[33]: 2
```

Why the first expression returns `1` (i.e. `Y`), while the condition is `True` and the "expected" answer is `0` (i.e. `X`)?

According to the docs:

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.
>
> The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

So, `True and 0 or 1` evaluates the first argument of the `and` operator, which is `True`. Then it returns the second argument, which is `0`.

Since the `True and 0` returns false value, the `or` operator returns the second argument (i.e. `1`)

Answer (score 4):

If we examine `A and B`, `B` will be evaluated only if `A` is `True`.

Like so, in `A or B`, `B` will only be evaluated in case `A` is `False`.

Therefore, `<condition> and X or Y` will return `X` if `<condition>` is `True` and `Y` if `<condition>`is `False`. This is a result of short-circuiting and the fact that `and` has precedence over `or`.

However, you should be careful with this approach. If `X` itself is evaluated to `False` (eg an empty string, list or `0`), `<condition> and X or Y` will return `Y` even if `<condition>` is `True`:

```
X = 1
Y = 2

print(True and X or Y)
>> 1
```

compared to:

```
X = 0  # or '' or []
Y = 2

print(True and X or Y)
>> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that first it will check `<condition>` if it's `True` then it execute `X` and skip executing `Y` if `X` evaluate to True

But if `<condition>` fails then it skip executing `X` and execute OR statement and execute `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is how python boolean operators [work](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

This makes use of the fact that precedence of `and` is higher than `or`.

So `<condition> and X or Y` is basically `(<condition> and X) or Y`. If `<condition> and X` evaluates to `True`, there is no need to evaluate further, as anything `True or Y` is `True`. If `<condition> and X` evaluates to `False`, then Y is returned as `False or Y` is basically `Y`.