# Logical AND operation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators

How does this expression work in Python?

```
x=1, y=2, z=3 
print(x and y and z)
```

Result is 3

If

```
x=3, y=2, z=1
print(x and y and z)
```

Result is 1

Anyone can explain this?

Comment: for me it gives 3 not 1

Comment: you either went `z and y and x` or `x=1; y=2; z=3`

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658308/how-does-the-logical-and-operator-work-with-integers-in-python).

Comment: The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Comment: `1 and 2 = 2 then 2 and 3 = 3, 
3 and 2 = 2 then 2 and 1 = 1`

Answer (score 0):

`or` operator in python returns first argument it is considered true, if not then it will return second. Neither value will be converted to boolean.
`and` operator will return first argument if it is considered false, otherwise second. Once again no conversion.

so `a or b` is `a` if `bool(a) == True` otherwise it's `b`
and `a and b` is `a` if `bool(a) == False` otherwise it's `b`

EDIT:
edited my mistake - i switched `and` and `or`

Comment: What you say seems opposite to what appears to be going on.  The OPs terms all evaluate to True, and yet the final value is what is the result, not the first.

Comment: Thank you, i forgot he asked about and, not or.

Answer (score 0):

In the logical test, the returned value is the one that has been evaluated last.
so , in first test ==> `print(1 and 2 and 3)`, the answer we get is `3` because it is last true value of the test.
In the second test ==> `print(3 and 2 and 1)`, similarly the answer is `1`.