# Why is my Python code printing like this?

Tags: python, logical-operators

I entered passed int values and tried boolean operations over it but I am not able to understand why it is giving this kind of output.

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
print(x and y)
print(x or y)
```

Output of the above code:

```
12
13

13
12
```

Comment: Show the output as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Does this answers your question. --  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658308/how-does-the-logical-and-operator-work-with-integers-in-python