# Is there any other meaning of 'AND' in Python?

Tags: python

I know that 'AND' is to give out a boolean value. eg:

```
x = 4 

x > 3 and x < 5
```

It will output `TRUE`

But when the code is:

```
18 and 4
```

it will output 4. What does it mean?

Comment: No idea, but `4 and 18` wil output `18`

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false and keep in mind that the result of `and` or `or` is the last term that was evaluated before succeeding or failing (this is the case for python as well as JavaScript, PHP and C if I recall correctly)

Comment: The definition of "A and B" in Python is this: if A is true, it returns B, otherwise it returns A.  Similarly "A or B" means "if A is false, return B, otherwise it returns A."  This gives it the usual Boolean meaning but also allows many more uses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the logical \`and\` operator work with integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658308/how-does-the-logical-and-operator-work-with-integers)

Comment: `and` (lower case) will return one of the operants. So, it will only return `True` (title case) if one of the operants was `True`. `p and q` is implemented as `q if p else p`.

Comment: In the olden days, Python didn't have boolean values. `a and b` is `b` if `a` is "truth-y", otherwise `a` (i.e. logically equivalent to `b if a else a`, but doesn't evaluate any operand more than once). `a or b` is `a` if it is "truth-y", otherwise `b` (`a if a else b`). The first language to use this convention was Lisp, in the late 1950s.

Comment: @apokryfos that explains why I can do something like `self.logger = logger or getLogger("dummy")`. My horizons have expanded.

Answer (score 0):

If the operands of and/or were not boolean values (True/False)

- And - > will return the operand at **left** (unless any operand is False/0, it will return False/0)
- Or -> will return the operand at **right** (unless it was False/0 and the other non False/0)

```
>>> 5 and 6
6
>>> 6 and 5
5
>>> 0 and 2 
0
>>> 0 or 2
2
>>> True and 2
2
>>> 2 and True
True
```