# Assigning an OR statement to a variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been looking for ways to assign a `or` statement to a variable, in a way that the variable can be used as a reference for other comparisons.

What i'm trying to accomplish by example:

```py
a = 1
b = 0

c = a or b
print(a == c) #would return True
print(b == c) #would also return True
```

Comment: So you are trying to make a function? Why would both return true (if this was possible)

Comment: `print(b == c)` returns False, quite correctly, because c is 1 and b is 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658308/how-does-the-logical-and-operator-work-with-integers

Comment: There are no "`or` statements; `or` is an operator used in *expressions*. Python doesn't support the kind of implication you are striving for here. (You can't say that `c` has two different values like this. Equality is transtive, so if `a == b` is false, there is no way you can say that `c == a` *and* `c == b` are true, at least not without providing a broken definition of `__eq__` on a custom class.)

Comment: Unlike operators such as `+`, `-`, etc, you cannot provide your own definitions of `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to want is somewhat close to the way sets work, with the operator `|` replacing `or` (which cannot be overridden):

```
a = {0}
b = {1}
c = a | b     # or a.union(b)
a.issubset(c)   # True
b.issubset(c)   # True
{3}.issubset(c)   # False
```

You could in principle make your own class that extends `set`:

```
class Singleton(set):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super().__init__([n])    
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.issubset(other) or other.issubset(self)
    
a = Singleton(1)
b = Singleton(0)
c = a | b
print(a == c) # True
print(b == c) # True
```

But it is doubtful whether the confusing code this generates would ever be worth it.

Comment: While this code is confusing for others to read, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the definition of the `==` operator by creating a class and replacing your integer values with objects that contain each integer, so you will be able to override the equal operator with the `__eq__` function. In this example, I will negate the result of the default operator to show you that you can apply whatever definition you need for that operation. The only disadvantage is that in Python, you can't override or redefine `or`:

```
class num:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        
    def __eq__(self, n):
        return not n==self.n

a = num(1)
b = num(0)

c = a or b
print(a == c)
print(b == c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get something like that by using `functools.partial` and `operator.or_`:

```
a=True
b=False
c = partial(or_, a,b)
c()
True
```

But beware, `a` and `b` are evaluated at definition time:

```
a=False
c()
True
```