# If And not taking second input

Tags: python, pycharm

my code for a random number guesser looks like so:

```
if answer == 'n' and 'N':
    print 'I hope to see you next time, %s' % user
    exit()
```

However, if I input `'N'`, the console blanks out and exits instead of printing the statement. `'n'` works still tho and the `'Y' and 'y'` statement works perfect. So I am not sure what is going on here with the `'N'`, but probably something simple I am overlooking. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's Logical Operator AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195322/pythons-logical-operator-and) and [How to test multiple variables against a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: @pault I have no idea why it reversed the order of you two dups when I dup-hammered your close vote. Do you think it's worth editing to put them in the original order, or just leave it?

Comment: @abarnert i think just leave it. Thanks for the hammer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your odd syntax that is failing you.

The interpreter interprets this as

```
if (answer=='n') and 'N':
```

Note that non-empty strings are evaluated as `True` regardless of contents, so this is equivalent to

```
if (answer=='n')
```

To fix this, replace this line with

```
if answer=='n' and answer=='N':
```

Note that this line should never evaluate to be true.

If you want it to work, you should try

```
if answer=='n' or answer=='N':
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is wrong.

First of all, when you are checking mutually exclusive inputs (in this case `n` or `N`), you must use `or` instead of `and`. `and` is used if you except both conditions to be met at the same time.

Secondly, you must use `if answer == 'n' or answer == 'N'` as your statement simply means `if answer is 'n' and True` as non-empty string evaluates to True.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors here.

First, `if answer == 'n' and 'N'` is not the correct way to check against two values.

In English, we can say "If the house is big or red" and we understand that "big" and "red" both refer to the house.  But Python isn't like this; you have to spell out each condition explicitly, like so:

```
if answer == 'n' and answer == 'N':
```

However, even if you do this, you still have a logic error: how can answer be equal to both `n` and `N` at the same time?  It can't.  Use `or` instead of `and`.

Comment: Can we not have three answer be essentially the same

Comment: @RushabhMehta this question is an obvious dupe. No need for even one answer here.

Comment: @pault That's fair too. I hadn't checked for dupes, but I totally see it now

Answer (score 0):

A more succinct and pythonic way would be:

```
if answer in {'n', 'N'}:
```

You are confusing `and` with `or`. You want the `print` to print when either of the two conditions is met.  So, you should be doing:

```
if answer == 'n' or answer == 'N':
```

Or, use the first way suggested.