# Why does 'or' only use the first value in python?

Tags: python

```
b = 'a'
print(b==('b' or 'a'))
```

You will get `False` if you enter this code.
But if you change the order like this:

```
b = 'a'
print(b==('a' or 'b'))
```

You get `True`.

So, why does `or` in this code only consider the first value of the two?
I think the upper code should also return `True`.

Comment: Read more about the operators.

Comment: Read the documention for `or`. You can't use `or` to check against multiple values if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: To be fair, "or" is a difficult thing to google about.  Here's the relevant section of the docs:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: In strings a non-empty string evaluates as `True` and an empty string evaluates as `False`.  `(X or Y or Z)` will return the first "Truthy" value or if none are "Truthy" it will return the last "Falsey" value.  So when you compare `b == ('a' or 'b')` it first evaluates `('a' or 'b')` to `'a'` and then compares that to `b`.  What you want is `b in ('a', 'b')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's Logical Operator AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195322/pythons-logical-operator-and)

Comment: Thx for U everyone!!! I understand :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try evaluating the following expression in the python REPL:

`'a' or 'b'`

This gives `'a'`, because the `or` operator short-circuits; that is, it returns the first truthy argument it finds, in this case, `'a'`. Both `'a'` and `'b'` are truthy, so you're simply getting whichever one of those you put first.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, you probably wanted to write:

```
b = 'a'
print(b in ('a', 'b'))
```

This checks if `b` equals one of `'a'` and `'b'`.