# Why is `True and ~True` -2?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm terribly sorry if this is below-standard question, but I couldn't find clear answers.

As the title says, why does `True and (~True)` give -2 while `True&(~True)` gives 0?
Also, Why do both of them not give `False`?

This is very counter-intuitive, since I expect for a single boolean expression `&` and `and` should work in the same way.

Comment: `True and (~True)` is equivalent to just `~True`, i.e. it returns the second operand. `&` does a bitwise operation with both operands.

Comment: What is ~true do you know

Comment: `~` is *bitwise* negation, btw. And Python `bool` objcts are just a subclass of `int` with exactly two members, `True == 1` and `False ==0`

Comment: `&` and `~` is the bitwise operators. For boolean operators, there are `and` and **`not`**.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Right now the only question in my head is why `True` is not defined as `int(-1)`, which would've made `~True` to be `False`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`True` has a value of 1 in Python. Bit-inverting (~) a binary 1 (...0001) gives you ...1110. Since negative integers are represented by [two's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), that's a value of -2.

Logical `and` returns its left operand if it's false, the right operand otherwise. (`True` is never false, obviously.)

Bitwise `&`, on the other hand, works on the individual bits. ...0001 & ...1110 have no 1 bits in the same position so they're all zeros in the result.

---

> I was just surprised that a numpy array with dtype=bool acts differently with literal bool

Each Python type can implement an operator's methods with special method names. (Like `.__invert__()` for `~`). But `and`, `or`, and `not` don't have these hooks, so often `&`, `|`, and `~` are used instead. For `int`s the implementation is bitwise, but other types can interpret operators however they want.

Note that `bool` is a subclass of `int` in Python, so it has the same operators as `int`. But you were operating on a `numpy.ndarray`, not on its individual components, so Python uses the `ndarray` implementation of the operators, which are not the same as `bool` when `dtype=bool`.

Comment: This is certainly not what I expected, especially considering that I deal with large numpy arrays and use `~` to negate anything, since `not` does not work on boolean arrays. Thank you for the detailed explanations.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_not.html

Comment: I know about it, but that's too wordy (thus leads to typos) when I write a long scripts, so I did not use it that often, and I don't think I'll use it a lot even after this fiasco... Or should I? I think it works exactly the same as `~`

Comment: Not if dtype is int.

Comment: Indeed, but I usually assign types very strictly so that's not something I'd encounter often. I was just surprised that a numpy array with `dtype=bool` acts differently with literal `bool`.

Comment: Each Python type can implement an operator's methods with [special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names). (Like `.__invert__()` for `~`). But `and`, `or`, and `not` don't have these hooks, so often `&`, `|`, and `~` are used instead. For ints the implementation is bitwise, but other types can interpret operators however they want.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, `True == 1` and `False == 0`.

So,

```py
True and (~True)
```

Is the same as

```py
1 and (~1)
```

[~ is a bitwise operation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). Which kind of inverts the binary of 1. If we

```py
print(~1)
```

> -2

So the whole thing is simplified into

```py
1 and -2
```

[Which is just -2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195322/pythons-logical-operator-and)

---

## `&` vs `and`

> I expect for a single boolean expression `&` and `and` should in the same way

Dont! `and` is a boolean test. `&` Is a bitwise operation. Both of them are very different.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanations. I assumed somehow a `bool` type literally has, one bit.

Comment: @interjay That's right, its best not to use `&` where `and` belongs :)