# Understanding the "and" operator - Why is "None and None" not False?

Tags: python

I though I understood Python the "and" operator. But after seeing

```
assert (None and None) is None
```

it was apparently that my understanding was not precise. Which was that `None and None` would be the same as `bool(None) and bool(None)`.

Does anybody have definition of the "and" operator and can explain the logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python's Logical Operator AND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195322/pythons-logical-operator-and)

Comment: What *is* your understanding of python's `and` operator?

Comment: "Does anybody have definition" - Yes, the documentation does. Why did you not read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation:

```
help('and')
```

> [...] The expression "x and y" first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false,
> its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting
> value is returned. [...]

Answer (score 2):

`and` returns the first value if it is *"falsey"**. Otherwise it returns the second one.

For example:

```
3 and 6 -> 6
0 and 7 -> 0
[] and 'abc' -> []
```

---

* a thing is *falsey* if `bool(thing)` is `False`