# Why does python print the integer instead of boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run `print(25 and 3)` in python, the output is always the latter value. In this case, it prints `3`, except when one of the values(at the place of 25 or 3) is a 0

`print(0 and 3)` would print 0

Why isn't it returning a boolean value?
How exactly is it being processed?

Comment: Check this out, it answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195322/pythons-logical-operator-and

Answer (score 3):

Because `and` isn't a Boolean operator. It uses Boolean logic, but does not necessarily produce a Boolean value as a result.

It uses the Boolean value of its first operand to determine which operand to evaluate to.

That is, `x and y` is basically equivalent to

```
y if bool(x) else x
```

rather than

```
bool(y) if bool(x) else bool(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

The short answer would be that these numbers have a boolean value. So 0 is False and anything else is True. For a longer explanation you can see that:
https://realpython.com/python-and-operator/